# Taking multiline user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Initially we don't know how many inputs we are going to take and input is given in the following format

```
sam
edward
harry
```

so far i have tried using split() and splitlines()

```
queryName = input().split('\n')
print(queryName)
```

It gives only ['sam'] and same result is for splitlines().
How can we take all those values as input?

Comment: How will you know when input is finished?

Comment: I am quoting the problem statement   " You will  be given an unknown number of names to query your phone book", and it is given in the format described above i.e one name each line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) reads a single line of input. You need to read in a loop.

Here I assume an empty input (i.e. two newlines after another) means the end of input:

```
result = []
while True:
    s = input()
    if s:
        result.append(s)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get all lines from standard input. That means it shouldn't be interactive because that never ends, e.g. it should be piped from a file or process.

```
import sys
lines = list(sys.stdin)
```

Alternatively:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    # do something with line
```